# Is it legit to edit tags then answer if it boosts my tag score?

Tags: discussion, tags, ethics, tag-score

Suppose I edit a question's tags, and then answer the question, thus boosting my tag score.

Is this legit?

The question is:

[Unlock the code!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/33871/unlock-the-code)

The puzzle could reasonably be tagged 'math' in my opinion.

Answer (score 6):

Don't feel bad to provide an answer and edit the question tags, as long as the answer does actually answer the question and the tags are appropriate.

It's "criminal" to introduce irrelevant tags or provide the answer just to gain some points towards the tag badge.